# How to add comment line in Far Manager's FarMenu.ini file?

Tags: comments, far-manager

**Context**

I usually edit Far Manager's <kbd>F2</kbd> menu editing FarMenu.ini as pure text file.
Pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> brings the menu open, then pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> opens the file in the editor.

**Question**

Is it possible to place comments in this FarMenu.ini file, if yes then what is the syntax?
(I've tried starting lines with `#` or `//` or `--` or `@`, neither work)

Comment: `#` should work, as long as it's a single-line comment. New line; another `#`

Comment: Many thx. It *seems to be*working but does not. First it does not show up in the menu (which is OK), but Far tries to execute it along with the command :-(. After it suddenly starts showing literally in the menu also... weird.

Answer (score 1):

- `#` - you will lose the lines if you edit the file using the interface
- `@rem` directly in the script

I've tested this and it works fine (as far as I can see):

```
# comment
t:   test
     @echo 1
     @rem some comment
     @echo 2
# another comment
e:   explorer
     explorer.
# final
```

If you edit it using the interface you will lose the comments.
Executing `test` I see the following output:

```
1
2
```

Answer (score 0):

The same as in bat-files:

```
:  test
   echo 1
   :: comment
   echo 2
   REM comment
   echo 3


Output:

echo 1
1

echo 2
2

echo 3
3
```

[More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16839602/273780)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).